# IOS/Objective-C: Direct users to specific screen of app on clicking on notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

In the default `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {` method in appDelegate, Apple includes the comment:

```
      //This may also be a good place to direct someone
 to a certain screen if the app was in background but they just clicked on a notification
```

I am trying to do this for local notifications, but can't figure out how to direct the user to a certain screen.  [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate?language=objc) say that you can check for an URL but even so, I don't know how to specify an NSUrl for a screen within an app.

This seems like a common use case, we click on notifications all the time that take us to specific parts of app, but not finding any good resources.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `didReceiveLocalNotification` or `didReceiveNotificationResponse` delegate method in your `AppDelegate.m` file based on which Notification you have implemented

**For UILocalNotification:**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
        // Your redirection code goes here like shown below
        MyViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

**For UNNotification**

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
       withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {

          // Your redirection code goes here like shown below
            MyViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
            [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
 }
```

For more reference on `UNNotification` or handling Local Notification, please refer https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html

Comment: What does the redirection code look like?  Also what is the kYourUniqueIDentifierKey in the case of a local notification?

Comment: @user6631314 I have edited my answer, you can check sample redirection code.

Comment: Does this apply to both UNNotification and UILocalNotification?  Also what is kYourUniqueIdentiferKey?

Comment: No there is different method to handle user's click in app for Push Notification(`UINotification`). And `kYourUniqueIdentiferKey` is any constant key which you have set at the time of passing data with `UILocalNotification`. And if don't pass any data then you can remove that condition in which I have mentioned that `kYourUniqueIdentiferKey`.

Comment: There is the old UILocalNotification (deprecated) and as of IOS 10, UNNotification.  Does the above work for UNNotification?

Comment: No for UNNotification, you have to handle different method which I have edited in my answer.

Comment: Ok. Thx!  I am supporting both apis